# jquery-mobile : how to make html <input type="button" side by side and 50% of the screen

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have tried almost everything, 
I am trying to get two buttons 
side by side evenly:

```
<input type="button" value="This week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[current_sunday]' /> 
<input type="button" value="Next week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[next_sunday]' />
```

Meaning  one button is 50% of the row and the other is the other 50%
so it will look like this:

```
{---------------------------------------}{--------------------------------------}
```

I need a way that works in **jquery mobile**, I have found ways that work for normal formats but I cannot find one that works with  jquery mobile and with `<input type"button"`

This:

```
<style>
.ui-block-a { width: 70% !important; }
.ui-block-b { width: 20% !important; }
</style>
<div class=ui-grid-a>
  <input type="button" value="This week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[current_sunday]' /> 
  <input type="button" value="Next week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[next_sunday]' />
</div>
```

does not work for `<input type="button"`   but works for `<button type="button">eat</button>`

using `data-inline="true"` like so :

```
<input type="button" data-inline="true" value="This week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[current_sunday]' /> 
<input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Next week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[next_sunday]' />
```

makes the buttons side by side but they are not 50% of the screen, the size of the button is big enough to fit the value.

RECAP: Away that makes two buttons side by side and each 50% of the screen, in  jquery mobile and `<input type="button"`

thanks

Comment: Where does JQuery Mobile come from?  Also, please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Just set `width` and `height` to `50%`

Comment: @ManofSnow  care to show an example please?

Comment: `<input type="button" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="This week's Schedule" onclick= 'window.location.href = dic[current_sunday]' />`

Comment: @ManofSnow that does not seem to be half and half. EVen when I do 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RECAP: Away that makes two buttons side by side and each 50% of the screen, in jquery mobile and